# Add a blog to the SharePoint SE

Tags: feature-request

It would be great to have a blog as part of the SP SE site, where the gurus can post articles, FAQs, etc. It could also have a way for users to submit blog articles they've written or found and have the moderators add them to the main blog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is absolutely possible!  We have setup a blog network called [Blog Overflow](http://blogoverflow.com).  We are happy to provide the resources needed to communities that show enough interest.

For more information about how you can get a SharePoint community blog, please see [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/).

Comment: Thank you, @Rebecca. I'm going to look into the links. Have a great day :)